# Resend failed request

Tags: java, kubernetes, microservices, istio

How can I configure istio for such case:

There is `serviceentry` with 10 external ip addresses. Two among them are broken.

I have configured circuit breaker, but don't quite sure is it possible to automatically resend request if it was failed on broken endpoint.  Or it just removes this endpoint from connection pool, returning failure to application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two fields under [TrafficPolicy](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#TrafficPolicy) which are relevant to circuit breaking: [ConnectionPoolSettings](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ConnectionPoolSettings) and [OutlierDetectionIn](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#OutlierDetection)

`ConnectionPoolSettings`, the volume of connections can be configured for a service.

`OutlierDetection` is for controlling the eviction of unhealthy services from the load balancing pool.

So the endpoint is removed till the circuit becomes `closed` again and the service will be allowed to handle requests again. You can't resend a request and don't need to because after a threshold when circuit comes in `closed` state requests will sent to that service automatically.

Comment: Thanks, for reply. Can you approve my thoughts: if my application sends request to unhealthy endpoint, that endpoint will be removed, but application will receive 503 error in any case? So, it is application responsible for retrying? I want to believe, there is a way when istio can retry failed request on unhealthy pod transparently for application

Comment: You can configure retry in istio by creating a virtual service https://istiobyexample.dev/retry/